# BeamRunJavaPipelineOperator settings in Airflow using GCP Dataflow (doing a non templated job!)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm struggling to get my `BeamRunJavaPipeline()` working in Airflow to run a Dataflow job on GCP.

I already have the jar file in Google Cloud Storage.

I'm basically looking for pointers and a practical example of how to get that pipeline up and running.

Answer (score 0):

This is some **good documentation to start with**:
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-apache-beam/stable/operators.html#java-pipelines-with-dataflowrunner

Look at the **required pipeline options**:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/setting-pipeline-options#set_required_options

It is also good to look to look at the **possible pipeline options**:
https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/pipeline-options#java

Here is a **code example**:

```py
your_java_task = BeamRunJavaPipelineOperator(
    task_id="your_java_task",
    jar="gs://gcs_location_where_your_jar_is_stored",
    runner="DataflowRunner",
    job_class="job_class_that_has_your_main_function",
    pipeline_options={
        "jobName": "your_java_task",

        # following options are required: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/setting-pipeline-options#set_required_options
        "project": "your_project_id",
        "tempLocation": "some_gcs_temp_location",
        "stagingLocation": "some_gcs_staging_location",
        "network": "your_network_name",  # you might not have to set this, but larger orgs might require this
        "subnetwork": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/your_project_id/regions/your_region/subnetworks/your_subnetwork_name",  # you might not have to set this, but larger orgs might require this

        # additional options, also required: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/reference/pipeline-options
        "serviceAccount": "email_address_of_your_service_account",
        "usePublicIps": False,  # otherwise dataflow will try to use external IP's, your org might not like this
        "numWorkers": 1,  # or higher, depending on what's needed
    },

    # setting pipeline_options["region"] = "europe-west4" results in Airflow thinking this task failing, so
    # having to set it in the dataflow_config.
    dataflow_config={
        "location": "europe-west4",
    },
)
```